# Adding a item to a list without a for loop in Salesforce

Tags: list, object, salesforce

Say for instance, I have a list of objects (obj1). Within each record of the obj1, there's a field value (var1). Is there anyway to add all the values of var1 within the list of obj1 to another list without looping through the list of obj1?

Please let me know if I am being unclear on what I am asking for above.

Thanks in advance for any help/clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are [SOQL Aggregate Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm), which will let you do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE IsClosed = false AND Probability > 60
```

That way you don't have to loop in your code and push the `SUM` operation to the database. On a related note, you might also want to look at [Roll-Up Summary Fields](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm) in case you want to maintain this summation on a parent object.